Moving values from of a given row in one column to correspond to a different row in R
I have novice experience with programming and the R language. I have the following sample of my dataset:
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

subsest_df <- data.frame(
  Condition = c("Oxidative", "Oxidative", "Oxidative", "Oxidative", "Oxidative", 
                "Oxidative", "Oxidative", "Oxidative"),
  gene_name = c("Atu0472", "Atu0472", "Atu0477", "Atu0477", "Atu0479", "Atu0479", "Atu0479", "Atu0479"),
column = c("1", "1_description", "1", "1_description", "1", "2", "1_description", "2_description"),
  COG = c("M", "Cell wall/membrane/envelope biogenesis", NA, NA, "E", "T", "Amino acid metabolism and transport", " Signal transduction"),
COG_description = c(NA, "Cell wall/membrane/envelope biogenesis", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Amino acid metabolism and transport", "Signal transduction"))

I would like to move the non-NA values in the COG_description column to be in the same row as a corresponding "1" or "2" in the "column" column, instead of the "1_description" or "2_description" rows, but maintaining the same matching values of "Condition" and "gene_name". The output I would like should look like this:
ideal_df <- data.frame(
Condition = c("Oxidative", "Oxidative", "Oxidative", "Oxidative"),
gene_name = c("Atu0472", "Atu0477", "Atu0479", "Atu0479"),
column = c("1", "1", "1", "2"),
COG = c("M", "NA", "E", "T"),
COG_description = c("Cell wall/membrane/envelope biogenesis", NA, "Amino acid metabolism and transport", "Signal transduction"))

With the help of our friendly robot chatgpt, we came up with an iterative structure for this but it ultimately fails with an empty output, and I am not skilled enough to figure out where the failure is occurring or why or how to ask better questions.
# Initialize an empty dataframe to store the transformed data
transformed_df <- data.frame(
  Condition = character(),
  gene_name = character(),
  column = character(),
  COG = character(),
  COG_description = character(),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# Iterate over each row
for (i in 1:nrow(subset_df)) {
  # Check if the current row is a description row
  if (grepl("_description", subset_df$column[i])) {
    # Extract the corresponding "_description" value
    description_value <- subset_df$COG_description[i]
    # Find the corresponding row with "1", "2", or "3" in the "column" column
    corresponding_row <- subset_df %>%
      filter(Condition == subset_df$Condition[i],
             gene_name == subset_df$gene_name[i],
             grepl("^\\d$", column))  # Matches only "1", "2", or "3" without "_description"
    # Check if a corresponding row is found
    if (nrow(corresponding_row) > 0) {
      # Add the corresponding row to the transformed dataframe with COG_description
      transformed_df <- rbind(transformed_df, corresponding_row %>% mutate(COG_description = description_value))
    }
  }
}

# View the transformed dataframe
print(transformed_df)

Thank you in advance for the help!

When adding one group based on column fill works for the wanted rows.
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Condition, gene_name, grp = sub(".*(\\d+).*", "\\1", column)) %>%
  fill(COG_description, .direction="updown") %>% 
  filter(grepl("^\\d+$", column)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grp)

output
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  Condition gene_name column COG   COG_description                       
  <chr>     <chr>     <chr>  <chr> <chr>                                 
1 Oxidative Atu0472   1      M     Cell wall/membrane/envelope biogenesis
2 Oxidative Atu0477   1      NA    NA                                    
3 Oxidative Atu0479   1      E     Amino acid metabolism and transport   
4 Oxidative Atu0479   2      T     Signal transduction


Thank you very much - this one worked out perfectly!

Here's a solution using dplyr. Split the data into the rows with descriptions and those without. Join the descriptions to the data.
library(dplyr)

subsest_df <- data.frame(
  Condition = c("Oxidative", "Oxidative", "Oxidative", "Oxidative", "Oxidative", 
                "Oxidative", "Oxidative", "Oxidative"),
  gene_name = c("Atu0472", "Atu0472", "Atu0477", "Atu0477", "Atu0479", "Atu0479", "Atu0479", "Atu0479"),
  column = c("1", "1_description", "1", "1_description", "1", "2", "1_description", "2_description"),
  COG = c("M", "Cell wall/membrane/envelope biogenesis", NA, NA, "E", "T", "Amino acid metabolism and transport", " Signal transduction"),
  COG_description = c(NA, "Cell wall/membrane/envelope biogenesis", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Amino acid metabolism and transport", "Signal transduction"))


# Create a lookup using the description rows
description_lookup <- subsest_df %>%
  filter(grepl("description", column)) %>%
  mutate(column = gsub("_description", "", column)) %>%
  select(gene_name, column, COG_description)

# Join it to the non-description rows of the original data
want <- subsest_df %>%
  filter(!grepl("description", column)) %>%
  select(-COG_description) %>%
  left_join(description_lookup, by = c("gene_name", "column"))


Thank you for the suggestion except the output resulted in numerous duplicated or triplicated rows when applied to my entire dataset.

You may need to include the Conditionvariable to the by= parameter of the  left_join and the select() in description_lookup.

Here's a dplyr::pivot_wider take.
subsest_df data is in a longer format (two rows per observation, "COG" and its "description"). mutate, by "major" observation (unique combination of Condition and gene_name), checks the variable name and value and cleans column to be another observation identifier. After that, pivot_wider just ensures there's one observation per row Condition, gene_name and column).
library(tidyverse)

output_df <- subsest_df %>% 
  mutate(
    .by    = c(Condition, gene_name), 
    .keep  = "none",
    name   = if_else(str_detect(column, "description"), "COG_description", "COG"),
    value  = if_else(!is.na(COG_description), COG_description, COG),
    column = as.numeric(str_extract(column, "^\\d+"))) %>% 
  
  pivot_wider() # `names_from` and `values_from` defaults: `name` and `value`

Output:
> output_df
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  Condition gene_name column COG   COG_description                       
  <chr>     <chr>      <dbl> <chr> <chr>                                 
1 Oxidative Atu0472        1 M     Cell wall/membrane/envelope biogenesis
2 Oxidative Atu0477        1 NA    NA                                    
3 Oxidative Atu0479        1 E     Amino acid metabolism and transport   
4 Oxidative Atu0479        2 T     Signal transduction   

Created on 2024-05-20 with reprex v2.1.0
